# Use of multiple <<<

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I am wondering about the way the redirection <<< works in `bash`. 
I understand that it redirects the chain after it to the command before as if the content was in virtual file. Examples

```
$ cut -d. -f1 <<< A.B
A
$ cut -d. -f1 <<< 'A.B
> C.D'
A
C
```

But I don't understand what it does when used multiple times. Example

```
$ cut -d. -f1 <<< A.B <<< C.D
C
```

I would have expected the following output

```
A
C
```

Why does the shell only take into account the last redirection ?
How could I add a virtual line to a file ? I would like to do something
like the following example, such that `command` takes the `virtual line`
and then processes the file `my_file`.

```
command <<< "virtual line" my_file
```

*Note* : I'm using `bash` version `4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<<<` redirects the stdin. If you redirect stdin and then redirect it again, the first redirection gets lost.

If the command has a way of saying "process stdin", which e.g. for `cat` is a dash, you can prepend a line in this way:

```
cat - input_file <<< 'virtual line'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It clarifies the way redirections are performed.

Answer (score 2):

Offering an alternative to [choroba's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/505816/20140), you can construct more complete input using syntax such as:

```
command  << EOF
virtual line
`cat input_file`
EOF
```